# I need to know if she is locked or can I do anything

Tags: engine

Nov18/19 oil change date plus new battery purchased was in formed that breaks and bushing need to be fix referred to another shop to look at. Car has been driven everyday and out of state no issues other than rpms a little higher than usual. Jan24/20 on a Friday morning my car wouldnt start so I checked battery good I check starter and oil levels.  My motor oil was so low only the tip of the stick had oil.  I called company whom I purchased the car from and also do my oil change since day one and explained the issues to him they towed my car to shop and called to tell me motor lock do to oil leak my car but I told him that's not possible since she has never leaked oil no spots outside in my garage she never leaked oil. Iv been having issues with oil being low in my car I have receipt of where I have purchased oil not even a week after an oil change which they credited me an oil change on my next visit.  When I called 3 days later to ask about my car if they have add oil or not.  He told me that it had a very bad oil leak since my visit in Nov. And that their was no need in adding oil to the car.  Why wouldnt he add oil if she was dry how is it possible that he not add oil first is that no obligated.  Please help me figure this out my car was fine never had any issues or signs know she is just parked I'm still paying notes on her.

Comment: How many miles (km) on the odometer?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. Please include all possible info about the car, including year/make/model/mileage.

Comment: I'll point out that it's quite possible to have a severe oil leak without any oil pooling on the ground.  It's also possible for the oil to get pulled into the engine and burned and there is little to no trace.  The low oil problem, regardless of HOW it happened, is definitely a potential cause for a locked engine.  I doubt anyone here can comment on WHY your service shop did or didn't do anything.

Comment: If there was oil on the stick, it wasn't nearly low enough to cause a lock. The dip stick doesn't typically protrude all the way to the bottom of the oil pan. The car can still have sufficient oil in it even if the stick is dry. (Though I'd not recommend driving it in that circumstance.)